# Orthogonal projection and orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am reading up for my exam in Linear Algebra and found the exercise:

Let W be a finite dimensinal subspace in an inner product space $V$, and let: 
$$P_W : V \to W,$$
be the corresponding orthogonal projetion on W. Show that the map: 
$$L: V \to W^{\bot}$$
given by 
$$ L(v) = v-P_w(v), \ for \ v\in V $$ 
defines an orthogonal projection on $W^{\bot}$

I am not really sure how I am supposed to prove this, I hope someone can either show it or give me a hint towards the method.

Comment: You have to prove that $L^2=L$ and that the range of $L$ is indeed $W^\perp$.

Comment: How do you determine that *any* linear map is an orthogonal projection? What are its characteristics?